# Save a file with app state in othe nPause() method in android

Tags: android, file

I want to write a incomplete app state to a file if user leaves the app without saving the state. I believe I have to use onPause(). Is this recommended practice?
(In onPause() i am going to encrypt the string and then create a file and store it, so bit time consuming).

If onPause() is not the place how to save the state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You an Save The Data `onResume()` State

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
       // DO your stuff here 
    }
```

Comment: is it recommended practice? If the operations are time consuming does it guarantee file save.

Comment: Its Just Depends On the Requirement .. There Are Many ways ..... when you are switching between activities You can override this method to Optimize

Comment: You can just save your bundle in onPause()

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android